# emacs: How do you copy a file?

Tags: file, emacs, copy, dired

In dired mode, how do you copy a file?

I pressed 'c' as mentioned in the manual but it's saying

```
Compress to:
```

I want to copy, not compress!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use upper-case C, not lower-case.